# add namespace and prefix to xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, apache-camel

I am using camel to route messages to a Webservice. The Messages are like XML but without namespaces/prefixes. The problem now is that the Webservice expects the XML but with the appropriate namespaces for each element. So as an example:

```
<a>
  <b>value_b</b>
  <c>value_c</c>
</a>
```

is what im getting in, but what needs to be sent out should look like this

```
<a  xmlns:n1="http://yadda-ns1.com" xmlns:n2="http://yadda-ns2.com">
  <ns1:b>value_b</ns1:b>
  <ns2:c>value_c</ns2:c>
</a>
```

if it was the same namespace on all elements i would have just used an xslt to add it. But its mostly 2 or 3 different namespaces.

Now is it possible to add the namespaces in my camel route? I had the idea to use jaxb to marshal from the "incomplete" XML to the "complete" one (with XML), would this work? I was trying this but did not succeed yet.

Or does someone have a different idea? What i also have in my project is the XSDs and JAXB Annotated Classes so these can also be used and the messages are identical apart from the missing namespace.

Best Regards

Thomas

Comment: Try using the same XSD for input as for output. Then the namespaces are allready good when receiving the request. Another option is to map the request to the response. I always use XmlBeans to generate a Jar from XSD's.

Comment: The Camel route im using, you can think of it as some kind of adapter for an old system (that sends the XML without namespace via tcp) and a new system (that receives proper XML via Webservice SOAP)  both the old and the new systems cannot be changed.
So i have to engage the problem in my adapter/camel route.

edit (also edited the question with that information): the messages are identical except for the namespace

Comment: "*if it was the same namespace on all elements i would have just used an xslt to add it. But its mostly 2 or 3 different namespaces.*" Why wouldn't you use XSLT for this? (And why is your question tagged `xslt` if you don't want to use it?)

Comment: xslt is not out of the solution pool. My experience with xslt is not that great and I only used it so far to remove namespaces and attributes. So I just put it aside thinking it might be more work, for example if the namespaces in the XSDs from the new System changes.
Or is it possible to somehow load that information from the XSD into the xslt?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the XML with a stylesheet such as the one below to modify the elements to be bound to the appropriate namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns1="http:yadayada-ns1.com"
    xmlns:ns2="http:yadayada-ns2.com">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template that copies content(unless more specific templates match) -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Make the "a" elements in the ns1 namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Make the "b" and "c" elements in the ns2 namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="b|c">
        <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: would it be possible to have ns1: with this solution for elements without having to name them all in the template match? something like `<xsl:template match="*">...`
But i think this would also include the root element right?
And then just individually do a template match on each that has a different namespace, this way i could maybe share the xslt among different messages.

Comment: Sure, you could use a more generic match and avoid naming each and every element name. If you don't want to modify the document element, add a specific path to the identity template (i.e. `match="/* | @* | node()"`). Depending on the combination of template match patterns, you might need to boost some with `@priority`